# Mysql subquery issues

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery, rdbms

Here is my mysql schema and query.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/73b0d/2

I want sum(each day's memo.discount), date, sum(each day's sale sum(item.sell_price)) in each row. But can't seem to find out the way. How can I do this?

Expected outcome.

```
total_discount    |      added_on        | total_sale
300               | 2014-06-25 00:00:00  | 1580
230               | 2014-06-26 00:00:00  | 980
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't know why you can't see. Here's the pastebin version.
schema : http://pastebin.com/VXRv3wvE

Comment: You existing sql has a sub query that brings back rows grouped by memo.added_on. There is nothing to join that to the main query

Comment: @Kickstart, I had to join memo_item and item tables to get the item's price.

Comment: But nothing in the sub query joins it to the main memo (alias m) table. Your sub query has a GROUP BY memo.added_on, but doesn't link that to the added_on date in the main query

Comment: Waaaah! THanks a lot @Kickstart for the hint. I really didn't have any idea that group by item can be linked to sub query this way. :)
just like a while loop. 
This solves my problem. 
select 
 sum(m.discount) as total_discount,
 m.added_on,
    
    (select sum(item.sell_price) as total_sold from memo 
join memo_item on memo_item.memo_id = memo.id
join item on item.id = memo_item.item_id
 where memo.added_on = m.added_on and memo.showroom_id = m.showroom_id) as total_sale

from memo m

where m.showroom_id = 2 and m.added_on between '2014-06-25' and '2014-06-26'
group by m.added_on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    SUM(m.discount) AS total_discount,
    m.added_on,
    sub0.total_sold AS total_sale
FROM memo m
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT DATE(memo.added_on) AS group_added_on, SUM(item.sell_price) AS total_sold 
    FROM memo 
    JOIN memo_item ON memo_item.memo_id = memo.id
    JOIN item ON item.id = memo_item.item_id
    WHERE memo.showroom_id = 2
    GROUP BY group_added_on
) sub0
ON group_added_on = DATE(m.added_on)
WHERE m.showroom_id = 2 and m.added_on BETWEEN '2014-06-25' AND '2014-06-26'
GROUP BY m.added_on
```

This has a sub query that gets the sum of the selling prices for each day for the showroom_id you are interested in, then joins that back against the memo table.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
select 
sum(m.discount) as total_discount,
m.added_on,
sum(item.sell_price) as total_sale
from memo m
join memo_item on memo_item.memo_id = m.id
join item on item.id = memo_item.item_id
where m.showroom_id = 2 and m.added_on between '2014-06-25' and '2014-06-26'
group by m.added_on
```

Edit: to use discount only from "memo" table... :

```
select
sum(discount) as total_discount,
added_on,
sum(subtotal_sale) as total_sale
from
(
select 
m.discount,
m.added_on,
sum(item.sell_price) as subtotal_sale
from memo m
join memo_item on memo_item.memo_id = m.id
join item on item.id = memo_item.item_id
where m.showroom_id = 2 and m.added_on between '2014-06-25' and '2014-06-26'
group by m.id
) h
group by added_on
```

Comment: check my expected outcome. Does it match with your's?

Comment: your answer gives total_discount 700 and 360 whereas my expected outcome's total_discount is 300 and 230 respectively.

Comment: ok, didn't realized that discount should only come from "memo" table... please check the improved query...